# update flamingo_inbound post type after insert

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-update-post

I'm having a difficult time trying to update the `flamingo_inbound` post author after insert.

Basically, I have a hidden field in `CTF7` for the company name that is being sent over and correctly stored in the db. That field corresponds to a particular company page.

Here's my code so far.

```
    function my_update_flamingo_inbound_author($post){

    $post_type = get_post_type($post);
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if($post_type == 'flamingo_inbound') {

        $company_name = get_post_meta($post_id, '_field_company-name', true);

        if($company_name)
        {
            $company_post = get_page_by_title($company_name, 'OBJECT', 'company');
            if($company_post)
            {
                $post_author = $company_post->post_author;      
                $post->post_author = $post_author;

                wp_update_post($post);          
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'new_to_publish',  'my_update_flamingo_inbound_author', 10);
```

Comment: have you verify that this hook is fired when you need it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flamingo plugin was adding the post and adding the meta data after. I was trying to access the meta data before it was inserted. I decided to use the added_post_meta and updated_post_meta actions instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **post type** within the **action name** and you gain the removing of an unnecessary check of the post type.

More on this [`wp_transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_transition_post_status/)

> For instance: When publishing a post for the first time, the post
>   status may transition from ‘draft’ – or some other status – to
>   ‘publish’. However, if a post is already published and is simply being
>   updated, the "old" and "new" statuses may both be ‘publish’ before and
>   after the transition.

`add_action( 'publish_flamingo_inbound',  'my_update_flamingo_inbound_author', 10);`

And removing the check for post type:

`if($post_type == 'flamingo_inbound') {`